# Refreshing a Bootstrap-Table Table with JavaScript Function

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-table

I have table built with `Bootstrap-Table`.

I am working on refreshing the data via `Javascript`. From the docs, it seems like I should destroy the table, then rebuild it.

I have successfully destroyed the table, but refreshing it does not and there are no errors in the console.

```
$(function () {
  $rebuild.click(function(){
      $('#table').bootstrapTable('load', data);
  });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rcr909rx/3/

Documentation: https://github.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table/issues/320

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the 'load' function. Destroy isn't required.

Like:

```
var newData = [
    {"name": "new data!"},
];

$('#table').bootstrapTable('load', {
    data: newData
});
```

I updated your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qxw5y72f/

Comment: Works great. Thank you!